# How do I pass variable from action to another action of a controller in yii?

Tags: yii

Here is my action

```
public function actionUpload()
    {
    $model=new Sop;
    if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    print_r($_POST['name']);exit;
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0];

    $filename = $_FILES['files']['name'][0];


        $new_url = Yii::app()->basePath."/docfile/".$filename;
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $new_url);
        /*if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $new_url)){
            //print_r($filename);exit;
            echo $filename;
        }*/
    }
    else "error";
}
```

Now i want to pass $tmp_name , $ filename and $new_url to another action in this controller.

Comment: Are you using Yii 2.0 or 1.1? There are many things that are different on 2.0 from 1.1

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve as actions within controllers are designed to be processing requests and generating responses. It seems you are not using the [Controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html) correctly.

If you however insist on using the controller-action you can use the redirect with a parameters as shown in the Documentation here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#redirect()-detail

An example could be (from inside a controller):

```
// /index.php?r=site/destination&tmp_name=$tmp_name&new_url=$new_url&filename=$filename

$this->redirect([
     'site/destination',
     'tmp_name' => $tmp_name,
     'new_url' => $new_url,
     'filename' => $filename,
]);
```

Please note that this is far from ideal. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but I would suggest using a [Component](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-component.html) for finishing the upload(?) job instead of sending parameters to a controller-action that finishes it.

Comment: Adding to this; you seem to be using Yii1 instead of Yii2 (consufing tags...?) for that you can look up documentation here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#redirect-detail

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$this->forward('action')` to execute another action without redirecting to that url:

```
$params = array(
    'tmp_name' => $tmp_name,
    'filename' => $filename,
    'new_url' => $new_url,
);
$action = $this->createUrl('controller/action', $params);
$this->forward($action);
```

The other action header could look like this:

```
public function actionAction($tmp_name, $filename, $new_url)
```

Comment: How I receive those variable in another action ?

Comment: @MohibulHasanRana As an argument for your action function

Comment: @MohibulHasanRana I added an example, but maybe you can add the code of the action that you want to use so we can give you a better suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

lets say you want to pass $tmp_name , $filename and $new_url parameters to an action named "next" in same controller, it can be done simply like this,
in your actionUpload() call action next as $this->actionnext($tmp_name , $filename and $new_url).

```
public function actionUpload()
{ 
  //code for actionupload() 
  $this->actionnext($tmp_name , $filename , $new_url); //call to  next action.

}
```

in controller, definition of actionnext() should look like this:

```
public function actionnext($tmp_name , $filename , $new_url) 
{
  //your code goes here.
}
```

and in actionnext function defination "$tmp_name , $ filename , $new_url" are just variables so you can use any name here.